# Authentication for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

For those of you familiar with M. Hartl's RoR Tutorial, do you know if the latest authentication system taught in the book is full proof for a large scale application or would you recommend going in with a ready made authentication systems like Devise or OAuth.

I find the system taught in the book very easy to follow as compared to the ready made systems. I am just not sure if there are any security loopholes in it.

Comment: not familiar with Hart's book, but i'm still sure Devise offers a wider range of functions and extensibility opportunities. For future. And most of the examples in books are very basic due to the books purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go with Devise.

Rolling out your own authentication system is great for practice, but many minds beats one, especially when it comes to security.